# Use the mid-point rule to approximate the area of the region bounded by a curve

Tags: calculus

My problem:

> Use the mid-point rule with $n = 2$ to approximate the area of the region bounded by $y=\sqrt[3]{16 - x^3}$, $y = x$, and $x = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have attempted graphing said functions and am not entirely sure which formula I should be using to determine the area.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drew a graph than you should see that the region for $x$ is $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $\sqrt[3]{16 - x^3}\geq x$ for these values of $x$. Since $n = 2$ we need to break up the interval $[0,2]$ into $2$ subintervals i.e. $[0,1], [1,2]$ each has length $1$ and the midpoints are $0.5$, and $0.5$ respectively. Plugging these values into $\sqrt[3]{16 - x^3}$ gives you the result i.e.

$$0.5(\sqrt[3]{16 - 0.5^3} - 0.5 + \sqrt[3]{16 - 0.5^3} - 0.5) = \text{some number}$$

Comment: Let me think..I see what you mean but I'm still unsure about the midpoints. Would they be the midpoints of the intervals or something else?

Comment: They would be the midpoints from the intervals, give it a try and let me know if you are stuck. I will add further details if needed, don't forget to vote if the answer helped :).

Comment: So (0, 0.5) and (0, 1.5)? And I did upvote, though I apparently need 15 reputation or more for it to be displayed publicly or something.

Comment: So with interval [0,1] the midpoint would be $(1 + 0)/2 = 0.5$

Comment: Gah, I meant (0.5, 0) and (1.5, 0), my bad. So...the Riemann sum...

Comment: I did a complete answer, please accept if satisfied :)

Comment: That definitely helps, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ....

Answer (score 0):

Sketch the graph of your functions to see what does the region look like. 
Find the limits of your integration and go from there.

The upper function minus the lower function is your integrand

Comment: I have graphed the three functions, but I'm not sure how to find the limits of integration.